# Import Content from BlogEngine 2.5 to Orchard 1.2

Tags: asp.net, orchardcms, blogengine.net

Has anyone been able to accomplish this? I'm considering moving my BE blog to Orchard MVC but do not want to invest time if there is no way to migrate the content...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BlogEngine and Orchard both support BlogML import and export. BlogEngine out of the box, and Orchard through a module.

Comment: I think the BlogEngines export method does not correctly tie in with the BlogML schema 100% correctly, so just watch out.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up Nicholas, In addition, I just realized that it's version 2.0, so not sure if that makes a difference?

Comment: The problem is that the person who wrong the BlogML export tool from the blog engine you use did not follow the BlogML Spec, instead, He followed about 85% of it.... Let me explain,BlogML does not have a notion of Tags, instead it has a notion of categories, The export file you have have both categories and tags, though alot more tags that categories.
Because Tags dont exist in the spec, they cant be imported.